# Signable, streamable, "readable" archive format?

Tags: file, zip, archive, signing, digital-certificate

Is there any archive format that offers the following:

1. be digitally sign-able with a digital certificate from a trusted source like Verisign - for preventing changes to the file (I am not referring to read only, but in case the file was changed it should no longer be signed telling the user this is not the original file)
2. be stream-able - be able to be opened even if not all of the content has been transferred (also not strictly linearly)
3. be "readable" - be able to read the data without extracting to a temporary folder (AFAIK if you open a file in a zip archive it is extracted first, and this stays true even for zip based formats like OOXML. This is not what I want)
4. be portable - support on at least Windows, Linux and Mac OS X is a must, or at least future support
5. be free of patents - Be open source - also preferably a license that allows commercial use(as far as i know GPL a share-alike license so it doesn't allow commercial use, BSD on the other hand allows it)

Note: Though it may come in handy eventually I can not think right now of a scenario that would require both point 1 and point 2 simultaneously. Or lets leave it a be able to check the signature only when the whole file was downloaded.

I am not interested in:

1. being able to be compressed
2. being supported on legacy systems

Does any existing archive format fit this description (tar evolutions like DAR and pax come to mind) ?
If there is, are there programing libraries available for the above mentioned OSs?
If not, would it be hard to create such a thing?

Usage scenario:
I want to use this to create a new media container.
Current media containers contain the audio, video and subtitle streams directly.
Matroska, currently the most advanced container, has supplementary features like attachments and menus.
The menu functionality however is not implemented and very limited.
What I want to create is one level higher.
I want to create a file similar in a way to OOXML.
Also all of the menuing should be done in web technologies like HTML5 (as it is now the  tag allows for any kind of codec to be used) and CSS.
Also just like you have holograms on dvds to prove the authenticity I want to create a sign-able file

Research notes:
Before asking this question I stumbled uppon this:
[Whats the best way digitally sign a zip file for download using .Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3625860/whats-the-best-way-digitally-sign-a-zip-file-for-download-using-net)

While detached signing would be feasable for the individual files contained in this archive it is not an ellegant solution for the archive file. Not end user friendly.End users should be able to doubleclick the file to open it in a media player like VLC, and see a message that the file is legit (just like you see in a browser if the page is transmitted with SSL through HTTPS or not)

EDIT: clarified point 5

EDIT 2: added a note to clarify point 1 and 2

EDIT 3: added usage scenario

EDIT 4: added research notes section

P.S.: This is my first question on StackOverflow

Comment: Re p.3: You can read directly from zip, and from pretty much any archive format. Files being extracted before use is a problem of the particular application.

Comment: Who voted to close? This is a perfectly valid question.

Comment: @atzz ZIPs are not streamable.

Comment: Digitally signable and "readable" seem to conflict with each other because at least the whole file has to be read to verify the digital signature.

Comment: @Eugene - I was commenting only p.3. Besides, zips *are* streamable: you can just read file entries one by one without waiting for the central directory to stream in.

Comment: @atzz not in context of the question (p.3) -- "also not strictly linearly".

Comment: @Eugene - this constraint is satisfied. You can skip file entries you don't need, and decompress those you need as soon as they stream in. Also, you can decompress only part of a file entry. This constraint wouldn't be satisfied if data required to decompress a file entry was distributed across the entire compressed stream, which is not the case with zip and most other compression formats in use.

Comment: @atzz I treat this constraint as a random access possibility (i.e. no need to scan the whole file). But nevermind, the OP probably knows better than me how he intends to use this format and what the constraints are.

Comment: @atzz, @Eugene: Added usage scenario. This should explain what I require by stream-able and read-able.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that you find such format out of the box. I understand how such solution can be built with help of our [SolFS](http://www.eldos.com/solfs/), but SolFS doesn't have built-in signing (you can add signing easily).

Comment: Wow. Incerdible thing. And it's great that it has so many apis available. It is actually overkill for what I want. Too bad it is not Open source. But I will defenetly check it out in more detail.

Comment: @alexvoda depends on what you call open source. If you need source, it's available. Not free, though.

Comment: As I see it I would fall in the middle-ware type of licensing. I want to create a media container and be free of pattent isues like the ones H.264 has for use with HTML5. Because of those isues WebM was created.

Comment: @alexvoda you are welcome to contact us via our helpdesk (http://www.eldos.com/helpdesk/) and there we can discuss SolFS-related topics in more details. There are lemmings on StackOverflow which become insane when they see commercial products being mentioned and discussed here.